# Excel If Statement (three text outputs)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I've been looking around and haven't been able to find an example of anyone publicly sharing the information I needed.

I'm trying to output three different results depending on the state of three different boxes: here's a general example of what I mean:

```
If Box 1 <> "" and Box 2 <>"" and Box 3 <> "" and Box 4 = "" Output Cat1
If Box 1 <> "" and Box 2 <> "" and  Box 3 = "" Output Cat2
If Box 1 <> "" and Box 2 = "" Output Cat3
```

Any help on how to make this happen inside of excel? It all needs to be inside of one box and obviously be determined on the content of the previous 3 so it cant be three completely separate rules.

Cant seem to get my formulae right!

Comment: With "boxes" you do mean "cells", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(A1 <> "", B1 <> "", C1 <> "", D1 = ""),
   "Cat1",
   IF(AND(A1 <> "", B1 <> "", C1 = ""),
      "Cat2",
      IF(AND(A1 <> "", B1 = ""),
         "Cat3",
         "<undefined result>"
      )
   )
)
```

`A1` is your "Box 1", `A2` your "Box 2" etc.

Comment: Great to hear that. If this answered your question, you might want to mark my answer as accepted.